# Why are some specific makes of car particularly vulnerable to catalytic converter theft?

Tags: exhaust, catalytic-converter

[The Guardian is reporting](https://www.theguardian.com/money/2024/jan/29/how-can-my-old-honda-jazz-be-too-high-risk-to-insure) that catalytic converter theft is an increasing problem, with knock on effects on insurance.  The particular example is of LV= which says of a discontinued insurance policy:

> only Honda Jazz SE models, made between 2001 and 2008, are affected because of the type of catalytic converter they have.

It surprised me that the risk was so different for such specific models that the whole insurance policy was considered unprofitable.  What is going on here?  Is it about ease of removal, the properties of the catalytic converter or the range of cars it will fit?  Another reason?

Comment: High ground clearance would make it easy to steal a cat.

Answer (score 1):

I think part of what you're not understanding is the theft of catalytic converters (cat for short) is not about refitting them to a different car, it's about reclamation of precious metals within the cat. These precious metals include platinum and palladium. The precious metals act as a catalyzing agent, which causes different "bad" gasses in the exhaust to be broken down into cleaner "good" (more like "better") gasses, which are then released into the atmosphere. Thieves sell these used cats to unscrupulous people who reclaim the metals and make money in doing so.

Some cats have the precious metals and some don't. It depends on how they are designed to work. If they do have the precious metals, this makes them more desirable to thieves. Secondarily to this is how easy the cat is to get at. Some cats are tucked up under far enough or attached directly to exhaust manifolds which make them a lot more problematic to remove. A thief will most likely go for the easy kill rather than on something which takes more time.